# Removing old references from designators in schematic

Tags: schematics, altium

How can I remove the old references from designators (shown with arrows) in the Altium schematic?
[image]

Comment: Annotate the project maybe. Another idea, there is the equivalent of component links in the schematic, I can't remember exaclty where to find it because I don't have alitum in front of me, but clear that and that should do it.

Comment: I don't remember but they go away eventually.

Comment: Maybe when you recompile the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

The shadows are compile results.  Evidently you have a hierarchical design.  It is showing what physical name(s) have been assigned to those components.  Select the tab at the bottom of the window ("Editor", "U_Magnetic Analog Front-End1", ...2, etc.) to see the physical names and other channel-specific annotations/variants.

Channel naming conventions can be changed on Project/Project Options, Multi-Channel tab.